# The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send

Tags: c#, paypal

I am trying to use DoDirectPayment method in my website.

This is the sample I am referring:

```
using com.paypal.sdk.services;
using com.paypal.sdk.profiles;
using com.paypal.sdk.util;
using com.paypal.soap.api;

namespace ASPDotNetSamples
{
    public class DoDirectPayment
    {
        public DoDirectPayment()
        {
        }
        public string DoDirectPaymentCode(string paymentAction, string amount, string creditCardType, string creditCardNumber, string expdate_month, string cvv2Number, string firstName, string lastName, string address1, string city, string state, string zip, string countryCode, string currencyCode)
        {

            com.paypal.soap.api.DoDirectPaymentReq req = new com.paypal.soap.api.DoDirectPaymentReq();


            NVPCallerServices caller = new NVPCallerServices();
            IAPIProfile profile = ProfileFactory.createSignatureAPIProfile();

            // Set up your API credentials, PayPal end point, API operation and version.
            profile.APIUsername = "sdk-three_api1.sdk.com";
            profile.APIPassword = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx";
            profile.APISignature = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
            profile.Environment = "sandbox";
            caller.APIProfile = profile;

            NVPCodec encoder = new NVPCodec();
            encoder["VERSION"] = "51.0";
            encoder["METHOD"] = "DoDirectPayment";

            // Add request-specific fields to the request.
            encoder["PAYMENTACTION"] = paymentAction;
            encoder["AMT"] = amount;
            encoder["CREDITCARDTYPE"] = creditCardType;
            encoder["ACCT"] = creditCardNumber;
            encoder["EXPDATE"] = expdate_month;
            encoder["CVV2"] = cvv2Number;
            encoder["FIRSTNAME"] = firstName;
            encoder["LASTNAME"] = lastName;
            encoder["STREET"] = address1;
            encoder["CITY"] = city;
            encoder["STATE"] = state;
            encoder["ZIP"] = zip;
            encoder["COUNTRYCODE"] = countryCode;
            encoder["CURRENCYCODE"] = currencyCode;

            // Execute the API operation and obtain the response.
            string pStrrequestforNvp = encoder.Encode();
            string pStresponsenvp = caller.Call(pStrrequestforNvp);

            NVPCodec decoder = new NVPCodec();
            decoder.Decode(pStresponsenvp);
            return decoder["ACK"];

        }
    }
}
```

This is the link:

https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/nvp_DoDirectPayment_cs.txt

When I pass appropriate parameter and try to run the code I get this error: "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send." on line:

```
pp_response = (DoDirectPaymentResponseType)caller.Call("DoDirectPayment", pp_Request);
```

The SOAP service call is inside the dll. Can anybody guide me what is happening and how to resolve it?

Comment: Hide your username and password!

Comment: @Alex: which one? This is the sample from the site! not my username and password.

Comment: sorry for that, I thought they were your private API keys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because that sample seems to be outdated, read up more on the stuff here:

- <strike>https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/sandbox</strike>
- <strike>https://www.x.com/developers/api-endpoints</strike>
- <strike>https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api</strike>

Comment: The link you gave doesn't contain anything by name of "Direct payment". Have they stopped supporting it?

Comment: @Jaggu if you took the time to look at the site you would have found the api documentation, I have updated my answer with one more link, hope it helps and that you understand that you need to make an account to be able to test the api.

Comment: thanks Joakim. I still am not able to find it. But your 3rd link helped me out.

Comment: Hi hot candy. You have successfully solved my issue. Don't know how to thank you!!! Thanks a lot!